# Setup android in intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am a newbie Android dev. I want to install android in intellij idea. But It notifies "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date ...". I downloaded SDK android and get directory for it. Unfortunately, It notifies "The selected directory is not valid home for Android SDK". Tks for your help!

Comment: Why not use Android Studio, which is the official IDE for Android?

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173890#comment=27-2207820.

Comment: Thank you. So I will use Android Studio for a while.